# Which overlay has the gui in it?

Tags: raspbian

Hello stack overflow community! I am not new to the raspberry pi.

My question is that in the `/boot/overlays` folder, where are the GUI overlays?

I just want to get rid of them so I can have just the pi terminal.

I am using raspbian.

Comment: There are no "GUI overlays".  The overlays are used to configure the GPIOs (or hardware generally).

Comment: You may configure the pi to boot into a CLI instead.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to pick apart the whole 'x' subsystem (that's a big job):

- Open the Terminal
- Run sudo raspi-config
- Take option 3 -> Boot options
- Take option B1 -> Desktop / CLI
- Select one of the console log-in options

After a reboot, you will be presented with the console command line or the prompt to log-in.  I would not use auto-login if anyone can get to the Pi :)

**Above assumes you are running RASPBIAN and reasonably up to date**

Edit:
If you really want to clear the SD card space (though it will not save you much) you could try removing / purging

- xserver-xorg
- xinit
- raspberrypi-ui-mods
- lightdm
- lxde
- RealVNC

My guess is that something will break though :-) as the last time I tried it (Stretch - possibly even Jessie) the boot was hanging.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to clean up a Raspbian installation to get a small installation without graphical user interface, only using the text console. Just install [Raspbian Buster Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). There you have what you want.